# code mirror using 40% cpu while idle

Tags: codemirror

Initial guess on why cpu at 40% while page is idle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I open http://codemirror.net/mode/xml in Chrome and look at the task manager, I see it taking 0% CPU. Thus, this is most likely something related to extensions you're using (the green/yellow gutter borders don't look familiar) or some other element on the page.